# Conjugaison du verbe "devenir"

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

D'après *Larousse*, le verbe "devenir" se conjugue avec l'auxiliaire "être"
au passé composé, mais il me semble que j'ai lu/entendu quelque part des formes comme "j'ai devenu". Peut-être j'ai tort. Pourriez-vous me confirmer que devenir se conjugue toujours avec "être" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je n'ai jamais trouvé cette conjugaison; je ne crois pas non plus qu'il existe de tournure idiomatique spéciale; cela ne signifie rien, autant que je sache.

Après une petite recherche j'ai trouvé de nombreux exemples dans [linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/j%27ai+devenu.html), mais ce sont des exemples marqués comme indésirables et de plus il contiennent d'autres erreurs qui montrent qu'ils émanent de personnes qui parlent mal le français. Aucun de ces exemples ne devrait être pris au sérieux.

Comment: Youpi, merci beaucoup !